# Largest subset of a group, such that no three elements multiplied equal the neutral element

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite abelian group (assume the decomposition is known) and the predicate $P$ be defined as $P(S) \iff \forall \rho,\sigma,\tau \in S, \rho\ne\sigma\ne\tau\ne\rho \colon \rho\sigma\tau\ne\iota$

Is there an efficient way to determine $\displaystyle\max_{S\subset G \wedge P(S)}|S|$?

If the problem is too hard consider the special case $G=\Bbb Z_3^4$.

Comment: bro the special case seems way easier

Comment: would solving it with brute force be of use to you?

Comment: What decomposition of G is assumed known? [of G into what type things, subgroups, etc.]

Comment: Are you assuming $G$ is abelian?  As you may be aware, your special case $G = (\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)^4$ is equivalent to the well-known question of many cards are needed to guarantee a set in the game Set.

Comment: Yes, the question for the special case did exactly arouse from the game Set! With a computer we were able to verify that in this special case the maximum is 20. But our program isn't so sophisticated and simply does nothing more than checking all cases.  And no, I wouldn't consider brute force an efficient way and by the "decomposition" I mean the uniquely determined simple groups that form an isomorphic group according to the Jordan–Hölder theorem

Comment: This is a wide open problem even asymptotically for vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_3$: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_set

Comment: Thank you very much! Reading this wiki article really baffled me. I didn't think this problem was that hard to solve.